# NetworkManager won't set static connection up if no physical connection when using Keyfile

Tags: linux, centos, networking, network-interface, networkmanager

When using NetworkManager Keyfile, a device will not be set up (to the static IP address) unless there is a physical connection or I manually do `nmcli connection up Onboard-NET`. I need the connection to always be up, for internal programs that use it.

Previously using this `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-net0`, the device would automatically be set to up:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
DEVICE=net0
NAME="Onboard NET"
HWADDR=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
IPADDR=192.x.x.x
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
PREFIX=24
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_DISABLED=yes
IPV6INIT=no
```

We can see that the even with no physical connection or manual commands, the device is up with assigned IP address.

```
net0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state ***DOWN*** group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.x.x.x/24 brd 192.9.201.255 scope global noprefixroute net0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### Now using Keyfile

Copying the settings to a keyfile: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Onboard-NET.nmconnection`:

```
[connection]
id=Onboard-NET
type=ethernet
interface-name=net0
autoconnect=yes # also tried =no

[ethernet]
mac-address=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

[ipv4]
address1=192.x.x.x/24
method=manual
never-default=true

[ipv6]
method=disabled
never-default=true
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy

[proxy]
```

On boot, the static ip address/connection is not automatically brought up:

```
net0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname eno1
    altname enp0s31f6
```

The connection will automatically come up if there is a physical connection to another machine, but if not it stays down until manually brought up. with `nmcli connection up Onboard-NET`. Now we can see it's up:

```
[amat@adt ~]$ nmcli connection up Onboard-NET
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2)
[amat@adt ~]$ ip a
net0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state **DOWN** group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:29:ad:8f:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname eno1
    altname enp0s31f6
    inet 192.x.x.x/24 brd 192.x.x.255 scope global noprefixroute net0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

#### Other possibly useful debugging info

- There is another connection, `ext0` (`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Onboard-EXT.nmconnection`) which is dhcp and used to connect to external internet. This one boots up correctly
- Devices are renamed in udev
- ifcfg method worked in CentOS 6/7/8
- systemd boot message for net0

```
NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1668115652.0180] manager: (net0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
NetworkManager[1037]: <info>  [1668115652.0182] device (net0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
```

- Using these kernel args:  `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0`

#### Edit

Issue persists when using ifcfg file (changing NetworkManager.conf to `[main] plugins=ifcfg-rh`

Could it be some power savings configuration or something? I don't understand why it's not listening to ONBOOT=yes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `ignore-carrier`? From the [`NetworkManager.conf` man-page](https://networkmanager.dev/docs/api/latest/NetworkManager.conf.html#ignore-carrier):

> `ignore-carrier`
>
> Specify devices for which `NetworkManager` will (partially) ignore the carrier state. Normally, for device types that support carrier-detect, such as Ethernet and InfiniBand, `NetworkManager` will only allow a connection to be activated on the device if carrier is present (ie, a cable is plugged in), and it will deactivate the device if carrier drops for more than a few seconds.
>
> A device with carrier ignored will allow activating connections on that device even when it does not have carrier, provided that the connection uses only statically-configured IP addresses. Additionally, it will allow any active connection (whether static or dynamic) to remain active on the device when carrier is lost.